# Visual Studio code and virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nose

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code with virtual environment.  In the Launch JSON I specify the nosetests launch like this:

```
{
    "name": "nosetests",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/env/dev/bin/nosetests",
    "args": [
        "--nocapture",
        "tests"
    ],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit"
    ]
},
```

However when I launch the environment variables do not get picked up.  I've tried setting up the python path in workspace settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/env/dev/bin/python"
```

but it doesn't seem to set the right environment.  There needs to be something that' the equivalent of source activate.  Has anyone figured it out?

Comment: FYI: the key for specifying python path in `launch.json` is now *just* `python`, for example `{ ... "python": "${workspaceRoot}/env/dev/bin/python" ... }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@mikebz you need to configure the path to the python executable as follows:

    `"pythonPath":"${workspaceRoot}/env/dev/bin/python"`

The path may not be 100% accurate (please double check it), but that's how you need to configure it in launch.json.
With the next version of VS Code you will no longer have to do this, i.e. you won't have to configure this same setting in two files.

More details on configuring the path for debugging can be found here:
https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version#python-version-used-for-debugging

Answer (score 4):

As 2018.03 there's an article how to add virtualenv to your python path list per particular workspace: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

All you have to do is `File->Save workspace as..` and then add to the settings of workspace virtualenv:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the path for your virtual environments in your workspace settings file: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Save your workspace then open `<workspace_name>.code-workspace` file and add your virtual environment folder to the settings:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "<path-to-your-workspace>"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.venvPath": "<path-to-your-virtual-env-folder>"
    }
}
```

After that open command palette (CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P) and type `select interpreter`. Then choose the one from the desired virtual environment.